# Need to pull data from mysql by unique userid, max rounds, then sort by another value

Tags: php, mysql, select, group-by

A couple months ago I asked a question about something similiar to this, received some help and thought I had the answer. 3 months later I am seeing this didnt work 100% so I need some more help but I can ask the question better now that I understand more.

I have a mysql table with `id, userid, rounds, reps, exerciseid`

I need to pull a users highest round specific to the exercise I am pulling for. So if the `exerciseid` was 8 I would need the users top round for that `exerciseid` but if the user has the same `rounds` more than once, which happens a lot, then I need to sort that by the `reps` to give me a true highest performance. Now, after obtaining those results I need to then sort this data set by `rounds`,`reps` so if multiple unique users have the same `rounds` that is then ordered by `reps`.

Can this be done with pure mysql or am I better off pulling the data and sorting everything with PHP?

```
SELECT
  max(l.rounds) as rounds,
  l.reps,l.userid
from leaderboard l
where l.exerciseid = 8 
group by l.userid 
order by 
  rounds desc,
  reps desc
```

example of structure
First this is a smaple set

```
userid  exerciseid  rounds  reps
--     --     --
1    8  23  10
1    8  23  15
1    8  20  10
2    8  28  19
2    8  15  12
3    8  40  29


results I want

userid  exerciseid  rounds  reps
--     --     --
3    8  40  29
2    8  28  19
1    8  23  15
```

Comment: can you add your existing query as well?

Comment: SELECT max(l.rounds) as rounds, l.reps,l.userid from leaderboard l 
where l.exerciseid  = 8 group by l.userid order by  rounds desc,reps desc

Comment: also could you elaborate: you want the highest rounds ( max(rounds) which would return the highest of them all) but at the same time you want to sort the outcome if there are more then one rounds per user per exercise?

Comment: yes, bascialy say I am userid 1, I have two rows with rounds 43 in each but the reps are 23 and 25 I would want the row with 25 because that was the highest performance. Then after I have that data set there might be another user, say userid 2 that has 43 rounds but 27 reps so he would be above me in order.

Comment: @Scott This is a little hard to conceptualize beyond what you have already tried. Please post a sample of the data directly from the table so we can see it in context

Comment: it sounds that you want the highest reps per user not rounds?

Comment: Michael, I have seen people post what looks like a mysql table format with lines around the data to help visualize and organize, I looked through the help but cannot find out how to do that and my attempts failed to keep the format. How can I post something like that to help you visualize it?

Comment: @Scott . . . Please provide sample data and results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Michael  Tilt I have edited my original post with a sample structure, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to first group by userid and rounds to get the maxreps on a round.  Then you want to select the max rounds from this.

Here is one way to express this in MySQL:

```
select userid, rounds, maxreps
from (SELECT userid, l.rounds, MAX(l.reps) as maxreps
      from leaderboard l
      where l.exerciseid = 8 
      group by l.userid, l.rounds
     ) ur
where exists (select 1 from leaderboard lb where ur.userid = lb.userid and lb.exerciseid = 8 group by lb.userid having max(rounds) = ur.rounds))
order by rounds desc, maxreps desc
```

Comment: Close, I want to group the users with their max rounds, then if they have a max round thats the same as another max round with that same exerciseid then grab the one with highest reps, the do that same sort feature all returned dataset so I have users highest rounds/ reps row per that exerciseid

Comment: @scott . . . I believe this is what the query does.  It may seem inverted because it handles reps then rounds.  However, it should be returning the userid, maximum rounds, and then max reps on the max round.

Comment: This worked good. I would never have come up with this. I had planned at this point to get the data and use php to do the work but this is fantastic. I appreciate your help, I appreciate everyones help for that matter. I will monitor the results for a while to make sure but for the test data set I put in it ran perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
SELECT
  max(l.rounds) as rounds,
  max(l.reps) as reps,l.userid
from leaderboard l
where l.exerciseid = 8 
group by l.userid, l.exerciseid 
order by 
  rounds desc,
  reps desc
```

Comment: Tilt, this pulled the same set that I had which is the users highest round and highest rep. The key to this is I dont want their highest round from one row and their highest rep from another I want their highest round then if there are two rows with that same round take the row with the higher rep then take that whole data set and order sort by rounds and reps the same way you did in the first part, but this part will be with each individual user.

Comment: if possible: could You give the data in the table (fragment of it) and the expected outcome. I think I don't quite understand what you're looking for right now..